# jQuery won't load txt in localhost or desktop

Tags: jquery

I know there are a ton of similar questions out there, but so far I haven't been able to get any of those solutions to work. Maybe I'm just missing something, but I've been trying to test a webpage that I'm building, and I don't have access to the server, so I need to test locally first. I'm trying to load and parse a csv/txt file using jQuery, but when I try and load the file, I get either a 0 or a 404 error. So I tried using a WW3 example and accomplishing the same thing locally, to see if my code was just way off base, but I get the same errors. I also tried loading up IIS and throwing all of the files on root, but I get the same issue. Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("http://localhost/demo_test.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
            if(statusTxt == "success")
                alert("External content loaded successfully!");
            if(statusTxt == "error")
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cant make ajax to an url with file protocol

---

Detailed answer: Browsers blocks file protocol requests by security reasons, if this rule was disabled every page could gather information of your computer without your knowledge. If you want to make an ajax to a file this must be hosted somewhere or you can create a virtual host, the most popular software as far as I know for creating virtual hosts are [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) and [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: okay, I'll try and set up xampp when I get home tonight. I'll update tomorrow whether or not I could get it to work. Would I put the entire suite of documents on the virtual host?

Comment: Its not really necessary, but it will emulate as if your files are already on the web, so its recommended